# spring cloud gateway + spring security and multiple oauth2 client

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm going to put a spring cloud gateway in front of some existing web applications which are already using keycloak as their identity provider and I want to authenticate the incoming requests inside the gateway. currently, each web application is already configured with the proper client-id and it redirects to the keycloak with the proper values. now, the gateway must do the authorization-code flow instead of each application, so it has to know in advance which client-is is for which requested url.
so, I was investigating how to implement it and I'm still here without any proper solution.
what is the solution for it? or, is it really a gateway responsibility to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found a solution however I'm not sure whether it's the best one.

```java
 @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll().and()
                .authorizeExchange().anyExchange().authenticated().and().csrf().disable().oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(createEntryPoints())
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(grantedAuthoritiesExtractor());
        return http.build();
    }

    public ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint createEntryPoints() {
        List<DelegateEntry> entryPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        entryPoints
                .add(new DelegateEntry(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/app1"),
                        new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint("/oauth2/authorization/client1")));
        //other clients will be added here
        DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint defaultEntryPoint = new DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint(
                entryPoints);
        defaultEntryPoint.setDefaultEntryPoint(new HttpStatusServerEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
        return defaultEntryPoint;
    }
```

so the client1 will be used for the /app1 and so on.
as i said earlier i'm not sure and there might be better solution for that.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look to this answer:

[How to create Spring Cloud gateway filter to add client-credentials access token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026345/how-to-create-spring-cloud-gateway-filter-to-add-client-credentials-access-token/70728340#70728340)

In order to support different client-ids (secrets, token-uris and so on), you can just define multiple configurations in **the spring.security.oauth2.client    .registration** section and make the clientid dynamic in the **Oauth2ClientGatewayFilter** class:

```
String clientId = ...
OAuth2AuthorizeRequest oAuth2AuthorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId(clientId)
                        .principal("myPrincipal").build();
```